# The base resistor of the transistor with speed-up capacitor

Tags: bjt

I've designed a relay driving cuicuit like this

[image]

Under DC the current is limited by R1. R2 is added to limit the current flow through C1 and the base of the BJT when the Q from 0 to 1. Is resistor R2 neccessary? And how to calculate its value?

Comment: Which resistor? At DC current is limited by R1 and R2.

Comment: I'm not convinced that R2 is even necessary. The intent of the speedup cap is provide a large base current initially and then tapper off. And when switching off, you want to put pull those charge carriers out of the base as quick as possibe. Adding R2 will slow that process down. This is assuming speed is what you are trying to achieve using a BJT.

Comment: AFAIK this speedup trick is used to switch the transistor realy fast (think < 1 us). Is this relevant when driving a relay, which takes >> 1 ms to switch? I would suggest using just a single base resistor. Don't forget the diode over the relay coil.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen good point. The speed won't be observed due to the on/off time of a relay.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Yes, the saved time is too small relevant to the switching time of the relay. But if it's not a relay? Is it neccessary?

Comment: @Andyaka: I mean the resistor R2.

Comment: @Diverger: neccessary for *what*?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: I mean if we don't consider the **low speed** of the relay drived (because this circuit may be used to drive other **faster** thing). And if we choose to use the speed-up capacitor. If it is neccessary to add R2 to limit the current?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resistor R2 is there to protect the CD4013 chip. If it is not present, the chip's output transistors will see a very low impedance to ground (through C1) for a short period of time when they change state and this could damage the chip.

To calculate a safe value, look at the maximum output current from the CD4013 and size R2 so that this is not exceeded when C1 is a short circuit.

As other commenters have stated, a relay is so slow to respond that a speed up capacitor won't have any appreciable affect on the performance of the circuit.

Comment: It could also be to protect the base of Q1 from excessive negative voltages.